# Modify script for working with jQuery-created DOM objects

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a very good function, that emulate "long click"

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.longClick = function(callback, timeout) {
        var timer;
        timeout = timeout || 500;
        $(this).mousedown(function() {
            timer = setTimeout(function() { callback(); }, timeout);
            return false;
        });
        $(document).mouseup(function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            return false;
        });
    };

})(jQuery);

$('#button').longClick(function(){ /* everything I want */ })
```

This code works fine with allready exist items.
But if I add this button to DOM via jQuery,  - this script doesnot work as well.
This construction also does not work with longClick, but work correct with 'click':

```
$(document).on('longClick',  "#button",function () {
        /* everything I want */
    });
```

How can I fix that?

Thanks!

===========
UPD

Here is another code, that works fine with original elements, but does not work with jQuery-added, but it use default methods.

```
var pressTimer;    
$("#button").mouseup(function(){
  clearTimeout(pressTimer)
  return false;
}).mousedown(function(){
  pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
         /* function */
  },500)
  return false; 
});
```

Comment: You need to extend the event system in jQuery, not add a plugin method. `$.fn.longClick` does not create a event named `"longclick"`, it just creates a method on jQuery objects.

Comment: I add another code with original jQuery methods, may be it will give you an idea how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: You need to extend the event system, read and understand all of this http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-extensions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good code is:

```
var pressTimer
$(document).on("mouseup", "#button", function(){
       clearTimeout(pressTimer)
  // Clear timeout
  return false;
})
$(document).on("mousedown", "#button", function(){
       // Set timeout
  pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
         /* MY SUPER FUNCTION */
  },500)
  return false; 
}  )
```

Answer (score 0):

To make some code work on not rendered items (such as those that are not initially added into DOM but rather added through jQuery or some other method) you have to use http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ ( .delegate() ) function of jQuery. So instead of doing:

```
$('#button').on('longClick',  "#button",function () { ...
```

you need to do

```
$(document).delegate('#button', 'longclick', function() {...
```

Hope it helps!

Edit 1:
Try it like this:

```
$(document).delegate('#button', 'mousedown', function(){
    clearTimeout(pressTimer)
    return false;
});
$(document).delegate('#button', 'mouseup', function(){
    pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function() { /* function */ },500);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: well delegate is the way to go, just make sure you've got the rest of the code right.

Comment: try using

var pressTimer;    
$(document).delegate('#button', 'mousedown', function(){
  clearTimeout(pressTimer)
  return false;
});
$(document).delegate('#button', 'mouseup', function(){
  pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
         /* function */
  },500)
  return false; 
});